# Why can't I import LinearLayoutManager and RecyclerView?

Tags: android, import

I can import everything else from the Android library except for those two. I'm trying to import them from `android.support.v7.widget` which doesn't work, but importing fragment and activity classes from `android.support.v4.widget` does work.

My Gradle Build looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.frisosapps.planner"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}
```

Should I add something to this or should I look for the cause elsewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use `RecyclerView`, use 
`compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'`

Comment: Since my buildToolsVersion is 22.0.1 should I change `v7:23.1.1` to `v7:22.0.1`?

Comment: @Friso1990 I would just advise you to upgrade your buildToolsVersion as well to `buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'`

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to include the RecyclerView dependency as its standalone library

```
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1"
```